# travic ci error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hashpw'

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm using travis ci with unittests.
the tests are working locally but it somehow fail in travis ci
this is part of the log.

```
======================================================================

ERROR: test_environment_is_development (test_config.TestConfigurations)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/travis/build/afaki077/minitweet/tests/base.py", line 17, in setUp

    self.create_user("admin", "ad@min.com", "adminpassword", confirmed=True)

  File "/home/travis/build/afaki077/minitweet/tests/base.py", line 33, in create_user

    u = User(name, email, password, bio, website, confirmed)

  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 306, in _initialize_instance

    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__

    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 183, in reraise

    raise value

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 303, in _initialize_instance

    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)

  File "/home/travis/build/afaki077/minitweet/minitweet_app/models.py", line 55, in __init__

    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 163, in generate_password_hash

    return bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(rounds))

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hashpw'
```

also travis is keep telling me my tests are passed although it doesn't

## Update

i was doing some tests locally and i delete py-bcrypt module with pip and run tests i got the same error on travis , when i reinstall it everything went fine.
(it's still broken on travis ci)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my problem the issue was travis ci is using an outdated version of pip
and the solution is simply add this to `.travis.yml`

```
install: "pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt"
```